# Counting instances of error case in node / JavaScript MySQL callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone tell me why `countDups` always elucidates to `0` and the assignment `countDups += 1;` in the callback `mySQLCallback` isn't respected?

Where should i Use `console.log(countDups)` to get the number of times the error `'ER_DUP_ENTRY'` was thrown?

I have tried all positions in the code, and declaring the variable `countDups` inside / outside every function.

I realise I can `console.log(countDups)` inside the `.each` loop, and print out every increment - but I'm only interested in the final value of `countDups`, not the value at every iteration. [Thanks to Svabael]

EDIT - Interestingly, I can make this work with promises or the async library but not with standard callbacks as per below. So thanks for any suggestions about other methods, but I'm interested in standard callbacks here specifically.

```
'use strict';

const url = require('url'),
fs = require('fs'),
cheerio = require('cheerio'),
moment = require('moment'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
request = require('request');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'host',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'pass',
  database : 'db'
});


var opt = {
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk/",   
    json: "",
    credentials: "",
    method: 'GET'
};


var countDups = 0;


var mySQLCallback = function(err, rows, fields) {

    if (err && err.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY'){

        countDups += 1;

        return;

      }
 };

request(opt, function(err, response, body) {

    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var tds = $('element');

    tds.each(function(){

        if (err) throw err;

        var type = $(this);

        var typeObj = {TYPE:type};

        connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLE SET ?', urlObj , mySQLCallback);

    });



    connection.end();

    console.log(countDups);



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the place that you have right now the `console.log` it will not work because you are increasing the counter in the callback of the query execution that is an async operation. If you place the `console.log` inside the error block then you should be able to see the counter increasing when you will find an error.

**EDIT**
Definitely there are more elegant ways to do it. In this case I've used a variable that plays the role of a semaphore. On every tds.each iteration we are increasing the var and every time that we have a response from the query we are decreasing it. When it will be zero, it means that we can safely return the results.

```
'use strict';

const url = require('url'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  moment = require('moment'),
  mysql = require('mysql'),
  request = require('request');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'host',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'db'
});

var opt = {
  url: "http://www.google.co.uk/",
  json: "",
  credentials: "",
  method: 'GET'
};

var countDups = 0;

function getLastCount (countDups) {
  console.log(countDups);
}

request(opt, function (err, response, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  var tds = $('element');
  var i = 0;

  tds.each(function () {
    if (err) { 
      throw err;
    }

    i++;

    var type = $(this);

    var typeObj = { TYPE: type };

    connection.query('INSERT INTO TABLE SET ?', urlObj, function (err, rows, fields) {
      if (err && err.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
        countDups += 1;
        console.log(countDups);
      }

      i--;

      if (i === 0) {
        getLastCount(countDups);
      }

    });
  });

  connection.end();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, in fact - I can see that happening. But I'm only interested in the 'final' value, not every value in the loop. I'll adjust the question based on your response, thank you.

Comment: @ApprenticeDev just edited the answer. I hope that I didn't do typos.

Comment: Great, have tested, and can get that to give me the correct result.

(Apologies, I'm a new user - Have up voted but it's not visible until I'm more popular!) 

Can you give me any insight into the theory / reasoning behind my original code not working? I feel as though I'm missing some fundamental aspect of callbacks here. 

Is there some special consideration for variable assignment inside error class / cases of a callback?

Comment: @ApprenticeDev cool! If that was helpful, you can accept the answer :)

Comment: @ApprenticeDev This specific snippet that you posted was working because you had a sync iteration `tds.each(function ()` and in there, you were executing an async operation (the query). So the iteration was ending very very fast but in the stack, there are the queries to need to be executed.   I think that you have to study more about the sync/async, iife, closures, execution context. I think that as soon as you will understand these concepts better then you will be able to structure the code better and therefore not to have these issues :)